Create a more compact code using some sort of iteration in pure CSS
I made a "load page" starting style for a series of elements.
Actually the main part of the CSS code is the following:
.col .card {
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
    transition-delay: calc(0.4s * var(--col-transition-delay));
    
    @starting-style {
      scale: 0;
    }
}

.col:nth-of-type(1) {
    --col-transition-delay: 1; 
}

.col:nth-of-type(2) {
    --col-transition-delay: 2; 
}

.col:nth-of-type(3) {
    --col-transition-delay: 3; 
}

.col:nth-of-type(4) {
    --col-transition-delay: 4; 
}

In SCSS should be simple to create an iterative version of this code, but how to create a more compact version of this CSS one?
I tried also to ask this question to Microsoft CoPilot but the solution was wrong... because in this way each item has the same transition-delay

Yes, you can definitely make this CSS code more compact by using a
loop-like structure with the :nth-of-type selector. Here’s a more
concise version:

.col:nth-of-type(n) {
    --col-transition-delay: n;
}


This code uses the n value directly in the :nth-of-type selector to
set the --col-transition-delay variable. This way, you don’t need to
write separate rules for each type.

Obviously it should even better if could be possible also to not be limited to only four items.

You can use @for loop of scss for this. Variables can be used inside the loop to create recursive selectors. Check out SCSS-For Loop for proper syntax and details. In case, you were wondering about the #{$var_name} syntax, check out SCSS-Interpolation
style.css
.card {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition-delay: calc(0.4s * var(--td) );
  @starting-style {
    scale: 0;
  }
}

@for $i from 1 through 3 {
        .card:nth-child(#{$i}){
          --td:#{$i};
        }
}

Html file
<div class="col">
  <div class="card" ></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card" > </div>
</div>


Thank you, effectively is a nice solution. But in case that I don't have control of generated html? Is a CMS and "cols" are generated by a default layout component. I have control of what is "inside" cols but not on cols themselves

Thank you for your updated solution Aniket but I explicitly wrote that I knew that could be "simple" in SCSS, but I looked for a CSS solution :-)

In that case you have make a compromise somewhere. Either edit your html according to the first solution I gave you or use scss. You can't have everythin, css is not there yet.
